# Error in VBA for powerpoint when trying to center a title(424: object required)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
With myPresentation.Slides(index).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        .Left = (ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - .Width) / 2
        .Top = (ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight - .Height) / 2
End With
```

So basically I have a slide with a 1 title object and I am trying to format it to be centered,

```
.Left = (ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - .Width) / 2
```

but this line throws an object required error. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Shape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shape-object-powerpoint) object has [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/shape-left-property-powerpoint), [`Top`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/shape-top-property-powerpoint), [`Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/shape-width-property-powerpoint), and [`Height`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/shape-height-property-powerpoint) properties. `TextFrame`, `TextRange`, and `Text` are irrelevant in this case.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CenterTitle()
    Dim myPresentation As Presentation: Set myPresentation = ActivePresentation

    With myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
        .Left = (myPresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - .Width) / 2
        .Top = (myPresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight - .Height) / 2
    End With
End Sub
```